# jquery access divs on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My javascript is dynamically generating contents `onclick`, and I would like to append the dynamically generated content to a div on another page, which will be opened after the click event.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // dynamically generate stuff in #storage-div
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('#storage-div').append(data);
  })
  $(document).load('url #target-div', function(target) {
    $(target).append('#storage-div');
  })
})
```

And I kept getting empty `#storage-div` because `ajax` is async.

What I want to do is putting a ref tag in `<head>`, like the ones for stylesheet, and then I can access `#storage-div` without having to use `ajax` again. Is it possible?

Comment: If I understand you want what you load in current page to be available in another page. That is not possible using ajax alone. If that is not what you are trying to accomplish provide a better explanation and some sample html showing what you want to insert where

Comment: @charlietfl I want to load a txt file in a div on a page temporarily, and then append this div to a div on another page.

Comment: You would need to use server side programming language to generate dynamic content then. Or do the same ajax in the other page. Html files are static resources.

Comment: Why are you wanting to go this unorthodox route? What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I guess what is being asked is... why can't you just do the same logic on the first page that you did on the second to get the data you need?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables only exist during a single page load. Even if you store it into a div, the next page load won't remember that. If you want to store JS variables and use them on another page, look at storage `localStorage`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Which then you can use like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // dynamically generate stuff in #storage-div
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    localStorage.setItem('some-var', data);
  })
})
```

Then on your second page get it.

`localStorage.getItem('some-var');`

Comment: Might as well just do the ajax in the other page

Comment: Edit in response to your response: True but I'm answering the "storage" portion of the question and `localStorage` is just to give an example way to solve the issue he presented.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put the storage div in a file, I will call it `test.html` here.
Since we are using `get` on the `dataurl` it should be cached and will be inserted on inside `storage-div` on each page after `storage-div` loads from the static html.

**Content of the** `test.html`

```
<body>
  <div id="storage-div">
    <div>I am here before in the markup.</div>
  </div>

  <div id="another-happy-div">
    <div>Happy Happy day</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**First page:** get that and append it to the body.

```js
$(function() {
  // note .one not .on here, only one time
  $('body').one('click', '#clicker', function() {
    $(this).hide(); //hide button, one only
    var url = "ajax/test.html"; // contains storage-div
    var dataurl = "somethingurlish";
    $.get(url, function(datahtml) {
      $(datahtml).find('#storage-div').appendTo('body');
      console.log('storage appended');
      $('#storage-div').load(dataurl, function() {
        console.log('storage loaded with data');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#storage-div {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

#target-div {
  background-color: #ffffdd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="clicker">Click Me</button>

  <div id="something">
    <div>whatever works for us, ajax after this at end of body</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Second page:** Get that and append to the other div

```js
$(function() {
  // note .one not .on here, only one time
  $('body').one('click', '#clicker', function() {
    var url = "ajax/test.html"; // contains storage-div
    $(this).hide(); //hide button, one only
    $('#target-div').load(url + " #storage-div", function() {
      console.log('target div loaded with storage-div');
      var dataurl = "somethingurlish";
      $.get(dataurl, function(datahtml) {
        // append to loaded content
        $('#storage-div').append(datahtml);
        console.log('storage appended');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#storage-div {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

#target-div {
  background-color: #ffffdd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="clicker">Click Me</button>
  <div id="target-div">
    <div>A targeting we will go, I get replaced</div>
  </div>
</body>
```